# I do get this error message in react-native when creating the apk file

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Good day friends , I have been trying to convert my react-native app to apk but I am getting the following errors. I actually succeed in converting it but when I try to run the app, it crashes without opening. How can I resolve this please?

````
[stderr] 
npm WARN
[stderr] 
deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[stderr] 
npm WARN
[stderr] 
deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[stderr] 
npm
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
WARN
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
deprecated
[stderr] 
source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[stderr] 
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[stderr] 
npm WARN deprecated
[stderr] 
resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[stderr] 
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
[stderr] 
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
added 1226 packages in 16s
63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details```
````

Comment: I don't see any errors there, just warnings. If they're annoying you can check out each of the links provided in the messages and see how to resolve them, but they don't prevent an npm install. Npm install warnings won't be the reason your app crashes, it's got to be something else.